# How To Get Amazon RDS Network Utilization Statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, bandwidth-measuring

With Amazon EC2 instances, one can use cloudwatch to find how much bandwidth is going in/out. However, this is not the case with the RDS database.

**Does anybody know of a way to discover the bandwidth utilization of RDS instances?**

I am hoping there is something slightly better than constantly polling the server with the following query:
`SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name IN ('Bytes_received','Bytes_sent');` [[source]](https://serverfault.com/questions/530310/how-to-estimate-network-data-transfer-volume-for-a-mysql-database)